# External access violation in Pascal - From where does it come from?

Tags: pascal, access-violation

when i try to run this code:

```
program Version_als_Kompilett;

uses SysUtils;

type
  tRefBinBaum = ^tBinBaum;
  tBinBaum = record
    wert: integer;
    li: tRefBinBaum;
    re: tRefBinBaum
  end;

  function initTree(): tRefBinBaum;
  var 
    Baum: tRefBinBaum;
  begin
    new(Baum);
    Baum^.wert := 30; //random(100);

    if (Baum = nil)         then writeln('Baum ist nil');
    if (Baum^.li = nil)     then writeln ('Baum links nil')        else writeln('Baum links                : ' + IntToStr(Baum^.li^.wert));
    if (Baum^.re = nil)     then writeln('Baum rechts nil')        else writeln('Baum rechts        : ' + IntToStr(Baum^.re^.wert));
    if (Baum^.li^.li = nil) then writeln('Baum links links nil')   else writeln('Baum links links   : ' + IntToStr(Baum^.li^.li^.wert));
    if (Baum^.li^.re = nil) then writeln('Baum links rechts nil')  else writeln('Baum links rechts  : ' + IntToStr(Baum^.li^.re^.wert));
    if (Baum^.re^.li = nil) then writeln('Baum rechts links nil')  else writeln('Baum rechts links  : ' + IntToStr(Baum^.re^.li^.wert));
    if (Baum^.re^.re = nil) then writeln('Baum rechts rechts nil') else writeln('Baum rechts rechts : ' + IntToStr(Baum^.re^.re^.wert));

    initTree := Baum;
  end;

var
  Testsubjekt: tRefBinBaum;

begin
  Testsubjekt := initTree();

  readln();
end.
```

I get this as a result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xKoN.png)

This line of code creates the problem:

```
if (Baum^.re = nil)     then writeln('Baum rechts nil')             else writeln('Baum rechts        : ' + IntToStr(Baum^.re^.wert));
```

1. Why does it happen ? The left child node seems to work, but not the right one.
2. How can I fix it ? I'm new in Object - Pascal.

I've tried around with various if - Statements. Then I have created this little compilable code. I'm using Lazarus as an IDE.

For tranlation: 'Baum' means 'tree' in english, 'Wert' ist 'value', 'rechts' is 'right' and 'links' is 'left'.

Comment: I would guess it's unhappy about reading `Baum^.re` when that field was not previously set, but then I haven't been a Pascal programmer for a long time.

Comment: When I compile your code (using Free Pascal Compiler on Linux) then it works for the first three if-statements (it prints "Baum links nil" and "Baum rechts nil", and if I comment the following lines then the program exits normally) but the EAccessViolation happens on the _next_ line, i.e., `Baum^.li^.li`. That makes sense because `Baum^.li` is null so you cannot access any further fields. Maybe your IDE has problems isolating/positioning the error, and it is actually on the next line for you as well?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

This is the classical ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior* example. There are 2 problems:

1. **Uninitialized pointers**

   [[FreePascal]: New](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/new.html) states (**emphasis** is mine):

   > The newly allocated memory **is not initialized in any way**, and may contain garbage data.

   You need to initialize the 2 subtrees to *nil*.

   **Note**: Tests on the other hand, revealed that *New* **does** initialize the 2 subtrees to *nil* (at least for *FreePascal 1.0.12*). But, other compilers might not, so it's best to always do it explicitly (although extra code is required)
2. **Accessing "illegal" memory**

   Every pointer must be checked for *nil* before being accessed (dereferenced).
   For example, you do check: `if (Baum^.li = nil)` which is good, but lower you dereference it: `if (Baum^.li^.li = nil)` which is not (when *Baum^.li* is *nil*).

   You have to reorganize a bit the code, and only access a subtree if its parent is not *nil*.

*Baum.pas*:

```pascal
program Baum;

uses SysUtils;


type
    PBinBaum = ^TBinBaum;
    TBinBaum = record
        wert: Integer;
        li: PBinBaum;
        re: PBinBaum
    end;


function InitTree(): PBinBaum;
    var
        baum: PBinBaum;
    begin
        New(baum);
        baum^.wert := 30;  //random(100);
        baum^.li := nil;
        baum^.re := nil;

    if (baum = nil) then
        writeln('Baum ist nil')
    else begin
        if (baum^.li = nil) then
            writeln ('Baum links nil')
        else begin
            writeln('Baum links: ' + IntToStr(baum^.li^.wert));
            if (baum^.li^.li = nil) then
                writeln('Baum links links nil')
            else
                writeln('Baum links links: ' + IntToStr(baum^.li^.li^.wert));
            if (baum^.li^.re = nil) then
                writeln('Baum links rechts nil')
            else
                writeln('Baum links rechts: ' + IntToStr(baum^.li^.re^.wert));
        end;
        if (baum^.re = nil) then
            writeln('Baum rechts nil')
        else begin
            writeln('Baum rechts: ' + IntToStr(baum^.re^.wert));
            if (baum^.re^.li = nil) then
                writeln('Baum rechts links nil')
            else
                writeln('Baum rechts links: ' + IntToStr(baum^.re^.li^.wert));
            if (baum^.re^.re = nil) then
                writeln('Baum rechts rechts nil')
            else
                writeln('Baum rechts rechts: ' + IntToStr(baum^.re^.re^.wert));
        end;
    end;
    initTree := baum;
end;


var
    pbb: PBinBaum;


begin
    pbb := InitTree();

    readln();
end.
```

**Output** (as expected):

> ```
> Running "e:\work\dev\stackexchange\stackoverflow\q076264860\baum.exe "
> Baum links nil
> Baum rechts nil
> ```

Also posting the image (made me nostalgic):

[image: img0]

**Notes**:

- For traversing the tree, you should use a recurring function (as you wouldn't want to change the code every time you add or remove nodes from the tree), but that's a different topic
- Generally, accessing illegal memory (that's not yours) may have 2 outcomes, depending of it being claimed by someone else:

  - Claimed: will crash with *SegFault* (*Access Violation*)
  - Not claimed: won't crash, but the contents would be garbage (and subject to change unexpectedly)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As an IDE I'm using Lazarus, because it feels way more modern than that FreePascal - IDE. I've tried to initialize the pointers with nil and it worked. Before i expected them to be automatically initialized with nil, because that was the way i was used to it from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling your program with FPC, and then running it:

```
% fpc Version_als_Kompilett.pas 
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.2.2 [2021/10/28] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2021 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Darwin for x86_64
Compiling Version_als_Kompilett.pas
Version_als_Kompilett.pas(37,3) Note: Local variable "Testsubjekt" is assigned but never used
Assembling version_als_kompilett
Linking Version_als_Kompilett
44 lines compiled, 0.7 sec
1 note(s) issued
% ./Version_als_Kompilett 
Baum links nil
Baum rechts nil
An unhandled exception occurred at $00000001054B9130:
EAccessViolation: Access violation
  $00000001054B9130
```

If both the `li` field and the `re` fields of `Baum` are `nil`, and your output shows that they *are*, then accessing a field on those is going to result in the memory access violation you're seeing.

This can be seen with a simpler program.

```
program test;
type
  tptr = ^t;
  t = record 
    v : integer;
    p : tptr;
  end;
var
  x : tptr;
begin
  new(x);
  if x^.p = nil then writeln('is nil');
  if x^.p^.p = nil then writeln('nil and nil');
end.
```

```
% fpc test.pas 
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.2.2 [2021/10/28] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2021 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Darwin for x86_64
Compiling test.pas
Assembling test
Linking test
14 lines compiled, 0.2 sec
% ./test
is nil
Runtime error 216 at $000000010CD629DB
  $000000010CD629DB
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to restructure my code with exit statements after the if - statements.